# Headi sql : sql error 1054

Tags: mysql, join

I have this code. Currently attempting to join three tables. Table names are confusing but this is what I have so far:

```
SELECT bx-book-ratings.isbn, bx-books.title, bx-users.location
      ,bx-book-ratings.book-rating
FROM `bx-book-ratings`
INNER JOIN `bx-users` 
   ON `bx-book-ratings`.user-id=`bx-users`.user-id
INNER JOIN `bx-books` 
   ON `bx-book-ratings`.isbn=`bx-books`.isbn
```

> Error: unknown column 'bx' in field list.

Any advice or tips would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Unquoted table names `bx-book-ratings`. Better change naming conventions and use aliases.

Comment: I get syntax errors straight away if the tables don't have back ticks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A dash character is not valid in an unescaped identifier.

The quick fix for your query is to just to escape all of the identifiers (table names and column names) by enclosing them in backticks.

For example:

```
SELECT `bx-book-ratings`.`isbn`
     , `bx-books`.`title`
     , `bx-users`.`location`
     , `bx-book-ratings`.`book-rating`
  FROM `bx-book-ratings`
  JOIN `bx-users` 
    ON `bx-book-ratings`.`user-id` = `bx-users`.`user-id`
  JOIN `bx-books` 
    ON `bx-books`.`isbn` = `bx-book-ratings`.`isbn`
```

You may want to consider avoiding using a dash character in any identifiers. (Renaming your tables and columns.) An underscore character is commonly used as a separator. I also recommend you consider assigning a short table alias in the query, and qualifying the column references with the alias.

For example:

```
SELECT r.isbn
     , b.title
     , u.location
     , r.book_rating
  FROM bx_book_ratings r
  JOIN bx_users u
    ON u.user_id = r.user_id
  JOIN bx_books b
    ON r.isbn = b.isbn
```

Comment: Yep, you're right spencer7593. Dashes are a big no-no. Thank you, im learning. Ive replaced all my raw data with underscores instead of dashes.Made it so much simply!!